# Form.Show(): Cannot access a disposed object

Tags: c#, winforms

I have been stuck with this for some time now. I can't open a new form on button click.
If i create and `.Show()` form in the start form constructor i will work. I dont get it! :-(

StartUp Form

```
public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        startmessage();
        br = Logic.loadXML("theshiiiiiittt.xml");
        br2 = br.Clone();
        loadboxes();
        //serializeTest();
        t = new Thread(contactDBUpdate);
        //t.IsBackground = true;
        t.Start();

    }
```

Button event:

```
private void resultButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ResultForm rf = new ResultForm(this);
        rf.Show();
        this.Enabled = false;
    }
```

Hope this is enough.

Comment: Is the click event firing correctly? Did you try putting something like MessageBox.Show("Test") in the event?

Comment: Could you post the stack trace?

Comment: I have tried putting using a MessageBox and i fire just fine. The button is not the problem :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found my code problem. 
I took one more look at the Stack trace and found i a message "Icon".

```
           this.Icon.Dispose();
```

Startupform had this line.

This code fixed my problem:

```
private void resultButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    ResultForm rf = new ResultForm(this);
    rf.Icon = this.Icon;
    rf.Show();
    this.Enabled = false;
}
```

Thanks for the helping hands...

Answer (score 6):

In my case it was caused by the fact that i wanted to make my forms non-modal. So i changed them from `form.ShowDialog(parentForm)` to `form.Show()`.

But that caused the `ObjectDisposedException` if i try to show a form a second time because somewhere in the code was `this.Close();`. [`Form.Close`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.close%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) also disposes it.

MSDN:

> When a form is closed, all resources created within the object are
>   closed and **the form is disposed**.

I just needed to change

```
this.Close();
```

to

```
this.Hide();
```

Comment: In case of multiple show and hide, won't it consume more memory?

Comment: Why? Hide just makes it invisible and show visible.

Comment: In VB.NET, all right is the Form is in My.Forms ? why ?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your form object loose the scope and is disposed off.
If you want to keep the dialog open, use `Form.ShowDialog()`;

Try this:

```
    private void resultButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using(ResultForm rf = new ResultForm(this))
        { 
          rf.ShowDialog();
        }
        this.Enabled = false;
    }
```

Comment: OP creates new instance of `ResultForm` each time. This can't be exception reason.

Answer (score 0):

Wile Implementing **singleton pattern on windows form** I got this error too.
The solution is that you have to assign a null value to the static reference in

```
protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
```

by putting simple line.

```
obj=null;  //obj is the static reference in the class.
```